# Highcharts need support for configuring CSS

Tags: highcharts

Style attributes like font-size,font-color.... all these were specified explicitly in java script,it would be great if i could define all styles in CSS including series colors, font family, size, color and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen paramter "style" for many elements? All of them are introduced here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts Morever you can set useHTML as true parameter, and use your own CSS styles.